# Missing a warning on unexpected implicit enum casts

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang, compiler-warnings

I have made a new Objective-C project in Xcode 10.2.1 (Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)), and have a code like this inside main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, Fruit) {
    Apple,
    Banana,
    Coconut,
};

void boolArg(BOOL b) { if (b) puts("boolArg"); }
void shortArg(short s) { if (s > 0) puts("shortArg"); }
void fruitArg(Fruit f) { if (f == Banana) puts("fruitArg"); }

int main() {
    Fruit f = Coconut;

    // NEED WARN: passing Fruit instead of a boolean, unexpected cast
    boolArg(f);

    // NEED WARN: fruit (NSUInteger) instead of a short, unexpected cast losing precision
    shortArg(f);

    // NEED WARN: passing boolean instead of a Fruit, unexpected cast
    fruitArg(YES);

    return 0;
}
```

In my codebase I'd like to protect from such implicit casts. Is it possible to enable some clang warning to catch this?

What I tried so far and it didn't help:

- enabled "Implicit Signedness Conversions" warning;
- added to "Other Warnings Flags": `-Wall`, `-Wextra`;
- change main.m to main.mm (to compile with Objective-C++) - only catches the last `fruitArg` call.

Comment: May not be the answer you're looking for, but if you want more stringent type checking, you can use C++ `enum class`.  If used ,`boolArg` and `shortArg` would cause compile time errors.